# trigger on contentdocumentLink

Tags: apex, trigger

can we create trigger on contentdocumentlink that fires on insert and checks if it's on account then mark a checkbox as checked?

Comment: we are not writing your trigger. Please at least share what you have tried so far.

Comment: i am asking is there a way to write trigger on contentlinkdoc

Comment: sorry, but that's not how it works. If you have a new question, create a new question instead of replacing the old question. Please revert your changes and create a [new question here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Why so many downvotes? guy was just asking whether it is possible or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if your question is, if it is possible, the answer is Yes.
Seems like others have done this already: [example 1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/166611/2513), [example 2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/130870/2513)

To create it, you can use the Developer Console, or you could use an IDE like [Force.com IDE in Eclipse](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE)

Comment: sure, glad I could help you!

Comment: how should i verify a contentdocumentlink is created in account from ui ??