# test class for a page reference method

Tags: apex, unit-test

i have a vf page which uses input file and simple upload button
standard controller is opportunity and extentention is cf

```
public class cf{
public blob file { get; set; }
private final Opportunity opp;
public cf(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {    
    this.opp = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();  
    }

public PageReference upload() {
    ContentVersion v = new ContentVersion();
    v.versionData = file;  
    v.title = 'dfgdf';
   v.PathOnClient=v.title;
    v.idopp__c=opp.id;
    insert v;
    return new PageReference('/' + v.id); 
}
```

}

I have problems in writing test class for it below is what i tried

```
 @isTest
private class Test_cf{

   @isTest
    static void test_upload(){
        test.startTest();
         Opportunity op= new Opportunity();
        op.Name= 'abc';
        op.StageName='Open';
        op.Trattativa__c = 'Automotive';
        op.CloseDate = date.valueOf('2017-11-12');
        op.Tipo_di_Trattativa__c = 'Cross Selling';
        insert op;

         ContentVersion v = new ContentVersion();
         Blob b=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');
         v.versionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('Unit Test Attachment Body');
         v.title = 'dfgdf';
         v.PathOnClient=v.title;
         v.idopp__c=op.id;
         insert v;
         PageReference pageRef = Page.cf;
         Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
         pageRef.getParameters().put('id', v.id);



        ApexPages.StandardController std = new ApexPages.StandardController(op);
        cf c = new cf(std);
        c.upload();
        test.stopTest();

    }

}
```

PageReference pageRef = Page.cf; giving me error page cf doesnt exits
from the forum i came to know cf should be the class name for which we are writing testcase.I even tried giving VF page name but no luck.

can some help me out with the test class

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
PageReference pageRef = Page.cf;
```

No, `Page.cf` should be the name of the **Visualforce** page, *not* the **Apex** controller. Change `cf` to whatever the name of your Visualforce is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
 @isTest
 public  class Test_cf{
  static testmethod void test_upload(){
     Opportunity op= new Opportunity();
    op.Name= 'abc';
    op.StageName='Open';
    op.Trattativa__c = 'Automotive';
    op.CloseDate = date.valueOf('2017-11-12');
    op.Tipo_di_Trattativa__c = 'Cross Selling';
    insert op;

      test.startTest();
     PageReference pageRef = Page.yourvfpagename;
      pageRef.getParameters().put('id', string.valueOf(op.id));
     Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

   ApexPages.StandardController std1 = new ApexPages.StandardController(op);
    cf c = new cf(std1);
    c.upload();
    test.stopTest();}}
```

Comment: getting below error System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [VersionData]: [VersionData] but i have populated version data field

Comment: Okay..error itself clears "you are missing required field in version".Itsnt because of page reference.Just run the code snippet in the anonymous window (CTRL+E) for inserting version.You can figure out that issue

Comment: if u can see my question on top , when i call cf.upload() in th etest class it calling upload  method in main class where there is a insert statement and it is failing there throwing DML exception saying missing version data filed but here in the test class i have already populated the filed.

Comment: @annppa - it got executed successfully on anonymous window

Comment: Go to this link you will get some idea  "https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/130870/contentdocumentlink-trigger-test-coverage-issue". I believe page reference issue is resolved. Thanks